# Why aren't Data Migrations a thing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration

Over the course of development, I've run in to tasks that I've done that required adding data to our db to make certain aspects of our software run. Whenever this occurs, I usually just make a migration to create the object; but this seems to be using migrations in a way that it was not intended. We could use a raketask, but for something that just needs to be added to all environments, that makes less sense (requires developer intervention to work, rather than just migrating).

This leads to the idea that there should be *data* migrations -- and it's such a natural line of thought that I figure since it doesn't exist, there must be a good reason why.

So -- why are data migrations not a thing? Or, alternately, how should such a task be worked?

Comment: Have you used `db:seed`?

Comment: That seems to be mainly for new databases -- this is adding value to potentially active + populated databases.

Comment: Perhaps a DataMigration doesn't exist as a migration type of its own simply because there's already a perfectly good way to achieve the same thing? I create migrations that insert data all the time -- generally data for use in the system, but not intended to be user or admin maintained.

Answer (score 0):

I can imagine some cases when data manipulation is perfectly valid inside a migration:

1. A 'product_code' column (of 'XYZ-12345' format) is split into 'manufacturer_code' ('XYZ') and 'seq_number' ('12345'). The sequence of adding two columns, updating them based on the value in the old column and finally dropping the old column can be thought as an atomic operation
2. StatusCode model, which is a lookup table of order statuses, with values like Active / Cancelled / Completed. Let's assume you make a change to the order handling process, which now can become Pending. This is less obvious than the previous example and many would argue with this, but I find adding the new StatusCode record by migration acceptable in this scenario. With such approach however, you should keep all status codes always maintained by migrations (and seeds, since data is not reflected in schema dump) and not allow manipulating them from a working application.

Note that in both of these cases data is never modified alone, it always accompanies structural or, at least, application code changes.